# Eliminate multiple conditions and reduce to one (without an OR statement)

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT  "listings".*, trucks.*, cars.*, trucks.id as truck_id, cars.id as cars_id, listings.id as listing_id
FROM "listings" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trucks" ON "trucks"."id" = "listings"."listable_id" AND "listings"."listable_type" = 'Truck' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."id" = "listings"."listable_id" AND "listings"."listable_type" = 'Car' 
WHERE (cars.user_id = 119 or trucks.user_id = 119) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Is there a way to modify this above sql do the same thing, but just call `user_id = 119` instead of using the `or` clause?

I would like to be able to do something like...

```
    SELECT  "listings".*, trucks.*, cars.*, trucks.id as truck_id, cars.id as cars_id, listings.id as listing_id
FROM "listings" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trucks" ON "trucks"."id" = "listings"."listable_id" AND "listings"."listable_type" = 'Truck' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."id" = "listings"."listable_id" AND "listings"."listable_type" = 'Car' 
WHERE (user_id_alias = 119) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

or something like

```
WHERE (alias.user_id = 119) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

The goal of simplifying the code is that I wrote a search query object that just cares about user_id, and since trucks and cars are mutually exclusive, as you can never have a listing with both trucks and cars, I needed to get all the listings for a specific user.

Comment: Join in the `user` table containing the user_id and filter on that. But I don't know what problem that solves for you...

Comment: what would the Sql look like? I am not great at SQL? Would I need two additional joins?

Comment: @JacobH, what do you think of 'LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "cars"."user_id" OR "users"."id" = "trucks"."user_id"')

Answer (score 1):

You can join `"listings"` and a union of `"cars"` and `"trucks"` tables.

```
SELECT  "listings".* 
FROM "listings" 
JOIN (
   SELECT 'Car' as "vtype", "id", "user_id"
   FROM "cars"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Truck' as "vtype", "id", "user_id"
   FROM "trucks"
) vehs ON vehs."id" = "listings"."listable_id"  AND "listings"."listable_type" = vehs."vtype" AND vehs."user_id" = 119
```

Comment: Very creative, also very informative, does this is faster or slower then just joining the user table as recommended above?

Comment: @user2012677 To speed it up one may try to apply `"user_id" = 119` to the union before joining. The optimizer probably is smart enough to push this predicate itself.

Answer (score 1):

I wold recommend writing this query using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM "listings" l
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM trucks t
              WHERE t.id = l.listable_id and l.listable_type = 'Truck' AND
                    t.user_id = 119
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM cars c
              WHERE c.id = l.listable_id and l.listable_type = 'Car' AND
                    c.user_id = 119
             )
LIMIT 1;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `trucks(id, user_id)` and `cars(id, user_id)`.  I would expect this to have very good performance (although the `left join` version might also be good).

I'm not sure this is the simplification that you want.  You could limit the `119` one place by doing:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM "listings" l CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (119)) v(user_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM trucks t
              WHERE t.id = l.listable_id and l.listable_type = 'Truck' AND
                    t.user_id = v.user_id
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM cars c
              WHERE c.id = l.listable_id and c.listable_type = 'Car' AND
                    c.user_id = v.user_id
             )
LIMIT 1;
```

I don't think that would affect performance.

Comment: What is the benefit of this? It seems even more complicated then my original?

Comment: Thank you, great tip, not right for this purpose, but I learning this is possible!

Comment: Nothing is going to be simpler than your original query. Are you only trying to reduce the number of lines?

Comment: I think joining the user table solves the problem. How do you think that effects performance?